# Random Color Deviation with Normal Distribution

Tags: javascript, random, colors, rgb, normal-distribution

I'd like to generate a random color, based on an original color and a normal distribution, so I can create a random texture telling the script "Okay, this is the general color you should be using, but if you differ greatly every now and then, that's fine".

I'm writing in JavaScript, using the Box-Muller transform. But if I use the normal distribution independently on every R, G and B value, I get undesired spikes. If my base color is a light grey, for example, I get pixels that are very red, very green or very blue. This is my script so far ("0, 255" being min and max):

```
function randomHex(hex, deviation){
    R = HexToR(hex);
    G = HexToG(hex);
    B = HexToB(hex);
    R = randomNormal(R, deviation, 0, 255);
    G = randomNormal(G, deviation, 0, 255);
    B = randomNormal(B, deviation, 0, 255);
    return RGBtoHex(R,G,B);
}
```

I think what I'm looking for is to somehow define a point in the 3D space of RGB color and then select a (uniformly distributed) random point on a sphere who's center is the defined point and who's radius is randomly generated with normal distribution.

That's the theory, anyway. I just don't have a clue how to make that work in JavaScript.

I'd be thankful for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try using HSV (or perhaps HSL) instead of RGB.  You'll need a function to convert back to RGB (see [here](http://snipplr.com/view/14590/hsv-to-rgb/) for an example).  In this case, H is the hue, and your value is some position on a circle of colors.  S and V control saturation and value/brightness respectively.  I think this will give you more control to get the distributions you're after.  More info on wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) too.

Comment: Interesting. I should look into that. I'm using it for Photoshop scripting and the HSB color model is accessible there (which is supposedly the same as HSV). But how would I randomize? Would each value receive its own normal distributed random number? That would spike in EITHER hue OR saturation OR brightness (and seldomly in more than one of the 3). Gotta try it out. Thanks! (don't have enough reputation to upvote yet, sorry.

Comment: I think it's something you'll want to play around with to get the results that you're after.  My guess is that you may want a normal distribution for hue, but maybe a different distribution for saturation and value/brightness.  It could just come down to tweaking each standard deviation (I doubt you'll want it to be the same for all three values)